# The intersection number $C\cdot D=\deg(D_{/C})$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $S$ be an algebraic complex surface, and $D=[(U_\alpha,f_{\alpha})]$ is a Cartier divisor over $S$, and let $\cal{O}_S(D)$ be the sheaf associated to $D$. And let $C$ be a complex compact curve in $S$, and let $\iota : C \to S$ be the inclusion map. Let's denote by $\cal{O}^D=\cal{O}_S/\cal{O}_S(-D)$. I use this notation to avoid the confusion with $\cal{O}_C$ the sheave of holomorphic functions on $C$. We have the two exact sequences:

$$0 \to \cal{O}_S(-C) \to \cal{O}_S \to \cal{O}^C \to 0,$$

$$0 \to \cal{O}_S(-C-D) \to \cal{O}_S(-D) \to \cal{O}^C \otimes \cal{O}_S(-D) \to 0.$$

Then $$(C.D)=\chi(\cal{O}_S)-\chi(\cal{O}_S(-C))-\chi(\cal{O}_S(-D))+\chi(\cal{O}_S(-C-D))= \chi(\cal{O}^C)-\chi(\cal{O}^C \otimes \cal{O}_S(-D)).$$

In the book of Chris Peters "AN INTRODUCTION TO COMPLEX ALGEBRAIC GEOMETRY :
WITH EMPHASIS ON THE THEORY OF SURFACES" he claim that by using Riemann-Roch theorem we get: $$(C.D)=\deg(D_{/C}),$$

where $D_{/C}(x)=\operatorname{ord}_x((f_\alpha)_{/C}))$, and $\alpha$ such that $x \in U_\alpha$.

First of all, I don't understand this claim.

Maybe we should prove that there exists an isomorphism between $\iota_{*}(\cal{O}_C)$ and $\cal{O}^C$, and an isomorphism between $\iota_{*}(\cal{O}^C \otimes \cal{O}_S(-D))$ and $ \cal{O}_C(-D_{/C})$ to answer this question, but I don't have an idea to prove it. In this case, we can conclude by using the fact $$\mathrm{H}^i(C,\cal{F})\simeq \mathrm{H}^i( S,\iota_{*}\cal{F}).$$

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: [Crossposted from MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4822228/question-on-intersection-theory-using-riemann-roch-theorem-to-prove-c-d-deg) - when crossposting, it is important to link all copies of your question together to prevent duplicating work.

Answer (score 5):

Let $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ be a scheme. Recall how one defines a closed subscheme. First we take a sheaf of ideals $\mathcal{I}$ of $\mathcal{O}_X$. The support of $\mathcal{O}_X / \mathcal{I}$ is a Zariski closed subset $Z \subset X$. And we DEFINE its structure sheaf by
$$
\mathcal{O}_Z := \mathcal{O}_X / \mathcal{I}.
$$

Thus, saying that $C$ is a curve embedded into $X$ is the same as saying $\mathcal{O}_C = \mathcal{O}_X / \mathcal{O}_X(-C)$.

I guess this is your only problem.